# REGEX to remove comments and leading/trailing whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to remove leading trailing whitespace and comments.

```
def func():
    text="""test1    #comments1
    test 2 blah      #comments2
    test3 4
    923423423        #comments3
    """
```

Desired result:

```
regextext="test1\ntest 2 blah\ntest3 4\n923423423"
```

I have the following so far:

```
(?:\s*(.*?)\s*)(?:#.*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/okF3mg/2

but it is missing the line without the comment

Comment: Shouldn't `"test3 4"` also be present in the desired output?

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I am asking about

Comment: Your "desired result" does not include "test3 4" though. Is that intentional,. or a typo, can you clarify?

Comment: how would you handle a string containing the `#` symbol? `test1 = 'some # text' #comment`

Comment: ah, that was a typo, I have edited the original post.  Since # indicates a comment, I would want 'some' and the comment would be '# test # comment'

Comment: if you’re just looking for the result, and don’t have to use regex “line = line.split(‘#’)[0]” handles basic cases well.  That said, regex is a good challenge here.

Comment: Yes, I do realize that, and that is how I have done it for a long time, but I figure it is about time I try to get better at using regex.  Also, have a multi-line string with comments in python is a fairly common thing I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this in a *single* regular expression, you can *match* leading whitespace, *capture* lazily-repeated characters, then *match* trailing whitespace and optional `#` substrings, and replace with the first captured group:

```
output = re.sub(r'(?m)^ *(.*?) *(?:#.*)?$', r'\1', input)
```

Comment: You could replace that lazy dot star with `[^#]*`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
text="""test1    #comments1
test 2 blah      #comments2
test3 4
923423423        #comments3
"""
new_result = re.sub('\s+#\w+(?=\n)', '', text)
```

Output:

```
'test1\ntest 2 blah\ntest3 4\n923423423\n'
```

Comment: This does not account for leading whitespace.

Comment: Then throw `re.sub(r'^\s*', '', text, flags=re.M)` on @CertainPerformance

Comment: I get "TypeError: sub() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'"  (I'm using 2.6.6)

Comment: Try , `re.sub(r'\s+#\w+(?=\n)', '', text, flags=re.M)`

Answer (score 0):

For any possible cases it would be good to include the flag inline to the pattern:

```
re.sub(r"(?m)\s+#\w+(?=\n)", " ", text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex string `^(.*?)(?:\s+#+.*|$)`.

This expression says to either find a `#comment` **or** the end of the line, so it will catch lines with no comments.

Python:

```
import re

text = """
for i in range(10):     # for loop
    print(i)            # prints number
print("Done.")          # prints "Done."
"""

regex = re.compile(r"^(.*?)(?:\s+#+.*|$)", re.MULTILINE)

matches = re.findall(regex, text)

new_text = ""

for i in matches:
    if i != "":
        new_text += i
        new_text += "\n"

print(new_text)
```

Output:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
print("Done.")
```